# Is there a way to earn money from non-mobile HTML5 game?

Tags: html5, monetization

I'm just a hobbyist, who has some ideas, that would not fit on a mobile screen. I have searched for some method, to make a bit of money from them, but I've found just for mobile-optimized games.

So the question is: is there any way to earn some money from these games, too?

Comment: Non-mobile html5 game is a web page. I wonder if there's any way for web pages to make money?

Comment: Adverts? Premium Chrome Web Store apps? Customer-only access to your website and game? Package your web app as a standalone executable and sell it?

Comment: Possibly related (since any HTML/JS game is de-facto open-source): http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/844/is-there-any-way-to-earn-money-with-an-open-source-game

Comment: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/13215/how-do-you-make-money-from-html5-games-i-e-sponsorships

Answer (score 2):

A non-mobile HTML5 game is a website. One way to monetize a website is through advertisement. A painless solution which requires minimal work on your part is a system like [Google Adsense](http://www.adsense.com/) which automatically chooses advertisement which might appeal to your audience, injects it into your website and pays you for every click.

You could also attempt to monetize your game through subscription or ingame micro transactions. But in that case you will have to create the payment infrastructure yourself and design your game in a way that these integrate well into the gameplay.

When you don't want your game to be embedded in a website and would rather want to market it as a stand-alone executable, there are also tools to wrap a web appliction in an executable. These usually work by creating a browser window without any toolbars or menus and loading your HTML page into it. Most users won't be able to  distinguish it from a native application. However, I never used a tool like this, so I don't feel comfortable making product recommendations in this regard.

You can then market it just like any other game, for example on a [digital download platform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category%3aOnline-only_retailers_of_video_games) like, for example, [Desura](http://www.desura.com/) (Steam would also be an option, but the [greenlight process](http://steamcommunity.com/workshop/about/?appid=765&section=faq) is a barrier which is too high for most hobbyists).